# Should cross-validation results be aggregated or not?

Tags: cross-validation, aggregation

When using repeated cross-validation for evaluation, should I aggregate the results for each cross-validation?

When aggregating, a 10-times repeated 10-fold, will provide 10 values for each measure like AUC. (Therefore, k=10 for my t-test with k-1 degrees of freedom when comparing algorithms.)

When not-aggregating, a 10-times repeated 10-fold will provide 100 values, as each fold is considered as a single run.

[WEKA](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) does not aggregate. However, [Han writes in his data mining book (p370)](http://ccs1.hnue.edu.vn/hungtd/DM2012/DataMining_BOOK.pdf) that each CV should be aggregated.

I personally am a fan of not-aggregating: a 10 x 10-fold CV produces 100 models, so one should use 100 results for comparison. Some of my colleagues disagree, though.

**Addition:**
I am doing the repeated CV for:

- Comparing two algorithms with a paired t-test
- Getting a variance estimate for my model performance

Comment: Practically how do you compare 100 numbers? The brains fits 7 at a time in any case. You'll end up aggregating in the end one way or another, explicitly or implictly. It's better to do explicitly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above WEKA uses the 100 results of the single folds as input for the (corrected resampled) t-test.

[According to a mailing list post](http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/Why-doesn-t-the-experimenter-aggregate-results-for-each-repetition-of-the-cross-validation-td38488.html), aggregating the results for each cross-validation run would lead to an increased Type I error rate (i.e., not existing significant differences are detected between algorithms).

Hence, each repetition of the cross-validation should NOT be aggregated before the t-test.