# Alternative aggregate measures in cross validation

Tags: cross-validation

We may have a process to produce a model, p.

We may evaluate a model, m, and find it scores $s_m=bananas(\hat Y_m, Y^*)$, for a hold-out set  $Y^*$, and having a variance, $var(s_m)$.

In cross validation, we may use the process to produce many models, and many scores and their variances:

$\{s_1, s_2, ... s_k \} $

$\{\sigma^2_1, \sigma^2_2, ..., \sigma^2_k \} $

Yet, when estimating the the performance of the process (p) (expected model performance), we typically use a [simple mean of aggregated results](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/240016/should-cross-validation-results-be-aggregated-or-not):

$s_p = { \sum_m s_m \over{ k} } $

and we've discarded the available information we have about the variance of each score. 
Wouldn't we do better to treat the final score as an equally weighted mixture of distributions of scores (with each distribution $i$ having mean $s_m$, and variance $\sigma^2_m$)? Or would we end up with the same $s_p$ and $\sigma^2_p$?

Comment: Can you re-phrase this question in a less formal way? Do I understand correctly that you want to rate your models trained during CV not only by the mean accuracy of each fold but also include the variance in accuracy? I was thinking about that as well, but I did not find a good way to incorporate both values into one score. I tried dividing the mean by the variance, but that was not giving me better models.